# Default value for std::ostringstream's string?

Tags: c++

I would like to know if `std::ostringstream` is always initialized with empty string.

```
std::ostringstream ss;

bool isEmpty = ss.str().empty();
```

Will `isEmpty` be always true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/ostringstream/).

```
default (1) 
explicit ostringstream (ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::out);
```

> (1) empty constructor (default constructor) Constructs an
>   ostringstream object with an empty sequence as content. Internally,
>   its ostream base constructor is passed a pointer to a stringbuf object
>   constructed with an argument based on which.

So, yes.